# Pass jquery variable to iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to pass the value which i get from a text box to the src of my iframe. I am using the following code to get the value from textbox, on the button click it should be passed to the iframe src and replace the query:'*' with the variable passed, i.e. the * should be replaced.
How to proceed with this?
Foloowing is the iframe with html code

```
 <iframe src="http://localhost:5601/#/dashboard/New-Dashboard?embed&_a
=(filters:!(),panels:!((col:1,id:env,row:1,size_x:4,size_y:3,type:visualization)
,(col:5,id:env-2,row:1,size_x:4,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:9,id:env-3,
row:1,size_x:4,size_y:3,type:visualization)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:
!t,query:'*')),title:'New%20Dashboard')&_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause
:!f,section:0,value:0),time:(from:now%2Fy,mode:quick,to:now%2Fy))" height="600" 
width="800" id="myframe"></iframe>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery With Example</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('.btnGetName').click(function (event) {
        var name = $('.txtName').val();
        alert(name);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
    <input type="text" class="txtName" value="hello" id="querypass"/><br />
    <button class="btnGetName">Get Name</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var src = $('#myframe').attr('src');
var newSrc = src.replace("query:'*'", "query:'" + name + "'");
$('#myframe').attr('src', newSrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

**Note:** Assuming that your `<iframe>` is within same HTML document:

```
$('.btnGetName').click(function (event) {
        var name = $('.txtName').val();
        alert(name);
        var iframeObj = $("#myframe");
        var srcString = iframeObj.attr("src");
        srcString = srcString.replace("query:'*'","query:'"+name+"'");
        iframeObj.attr("src",srcString );
});
```

Please make sure that you don't put single quote in your text field.